# Not able to figure out why the reload data method is loading same data for different data source objects

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uicollectionview

In the following code I am creating dataSources objects and adding them to an array of data sources and later I am providing this objects to the respective collections like "Upcoming Movies" and "Top Rated Movies" which is identified by **isLatest, isNowPlaying, isUpcoming, isTopRated** properties of Core Data Entities. Basically it is a collection of collections.

The problem I am facing is that I am not able to debug out why the reload data method is loading same data(movies) for different data source objects in the collections.

I have wasted a lot of time debugging in the code to find out the problem. Any help would be appreciated to find out the problem in the code. **Following is the public url of the Github project. Thanks in Advance.**

https://github.com/amit2908/Moview.git

```
func loadUpcomingMovies(page: Int, handler: @escaping FetchMoviesFromSourceCompletionHandler) {
    modelLayer.loadUpcomingMovies(from: .local, page: page) { (movies, source, error) -> (Void) in
        if (error == nil) {
            if movies.count != 0 {
                self.movieDataSources[0] = MovieCollectionDataSource(movies: movies)
            }
            handler(.local)
        }
    }

    modelLayer.loadUpcomingMovies(from: .network, page: page) { (movies, source, error) -> (Void) in
        if (error == nil) {
            if movies.count != 0 {
                self.movieDataSources[0] = MovieCollectionDataSource(movies: movies)
            }
            handler(.network)
        }
    }

}

func loadTopRatedMovies(page: Int, handler: @escaping FetchMoviesFromSourceCompletionHandler) {
    modelLayer.loadTopRatedMovies(from: .local, page: page) { (movies, source, error) -> (Void) in
        if (error == nil) {
            if movies.count != 0 {
                self.movieDataSources[1] = MovieCollectionDataSource(movies: movies)
            }
            handler(.local)
        }
    }

    modelLayer.loadTopRatedMovies(from: .network, page: page) { (movies, source, error) -> (Void) in
        if (error == nil) {
            if movies.count != 0 {
                self.movieDataSources[1] = MovieCollectionDataSource(movies: movies)
            }
            handler(.network)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you using the same index everywhere, `self.movieDataSources[1]`?

Comment: Haven't been through your code, but I'll take a guess that the problem is that your attribute names begin "is...".  There seems to be a bug in CoreData that causes it to get confused with predicates using such attribute names.  Try a different name.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have updated the code. In this code, I am not using the same index.

Comment: I suggest you to go to the Github link and download the project and run it.

Comment: I asked a question and you haven't answered it or explained why you now have changed the code. Did the change improve anything?

Comment: Extremely Sorry but actually there was another method named loadLatestMovie which had the same index, which shouldn't be the part of the question, instead loadUpcomingMovies should be. I have that's why updated the code. Please go to the public link. https://github.com/amit2908/Moview.git to find the complete project.